# Importing data into Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hello i have been trying to import the Covid 19 dataset to be specific into mysql workbench and its taking like hours with no completion can someone kindly assist how did they go about if they did any importation of the same dataset into mysql workbench

Tried to import the covid dataset ,takes too long with no completion,expecting someone to help me import the data in the fastest way out

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a tool not a DBMS! Which dataset? How are you importing it??

Answer (score 0):

Guess it depends on your dataset.
I presume it's a self-contained sql file?

If that is the case you could try the following:

navigate to Server, data import.

Select the Import from Self-Contained File radio button

then just press start Import on the bottom right